# Error when trying to load storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am loading a storyboard with the name "Main" and StoryBoardID "loginPage" from an xib button click. Everything was working fine till yesterday and now, I get this error on the button click which takes me to the storyboard:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''

I'm using Xcode 6.4

Please help!!

Comment: Have you renamed any file in your project?

Comment: could you post the error

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the storyboard file.
2. Select the target Controller scene for login page button click.
3. Check the Identity inspector of Utilities are of that scene.
4. Give the proper name for **class**(targeted class name from bundle) and
   **storyboard ID**(any name for that class).
5. Use the **storyboard ID** in the code for creating the controller
   object.

Answer (score 0):

Check your storyboard is there or you have not removed the reference of it.
And check in nib name you are passing the correct string of storyboard.Bundle should be the same where your storyboard file is.

Answer (score 0):

1) Visit the properties of the "loginPage" files in the file inspector.

2) the property "Target Membership" pitch on the select box

3) Then your loginPage file was linked with your target.

check it out.

Comment: Target Membership is checked. All this started when I started had to create a storyboard for iPad. The first page is an xib loaded from appdelegates and this page is linked to storyboard. The names are the same and everything. i get this error on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: And.. By the way.. These changes are not committed to the git. We use SourceControl. Is there anyway for me to delete this and reload the whole project from the git?

Comment: as you said yesterday it's working fine then take yesterday's project and check it out where actually you have done mistake.